# Find the number of employees in each department using rollup

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

so i use code like this:

```
select count(*) as count, d.department_name 
from employees e inner join departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id 
group by d.department_name;
```

but I want to add a rollup function, how do I do it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Microsoft Windows `cmd.exe`, so removing `cmd` tag. It has everything to do with the SQL language.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
  SELECT COUNT (*) AS COUNT, d.department_name
    FROM employees e
         INNER JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
GROUP BY ROLLUP (d.department_name);
```